# Preact "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Tags: server-side-rendering, prerender, preact

I'm trying to use a web API in my Preact app and can't seem to find a workaround for this error

```
Build  [=================== ] 93% (10.2s) after chunk asset optimization
ReferenceError: window is not defined
method: UqHU

Stack:

{
    "fileName": "D:\\preact-app\\build\\ssr-build\\ssr-bundle.js",
    "lineNumber": 1,
    "functionName": "Object.UqHU",
    "methodName": "UqHU",
    "columnNumber": 93549,
    "native": false
}
This is most likely caused by using DOM or Web APIs.
Pre-render runs in node and has no access to globals available in browsers.

Consider wrapping code producing error in: "if (typeof window !== "undefined") { ... }"

Alternatively use "preact build --no-prerender" to disable prerendering.

See https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli#pre-rendering for further information.
```

I have tried "if (typeof window !== "undefined")" but still getting the same error. Commenting out the code or using --no-prerender solves it

Comment: If `--no-prerender` solves your issue, what exactly is the question?

Comment: @SzigetiPéter They want to avoid the need to disable prerendering, clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the import of axios, which depends on the "form-data" library and is not compatible with Preact prerendering as far as I understand. I chose to use fetch instead of axios to fix this but rschristian gives more solutions in this post: https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/discussions/1784

Answer (score 0):

`preact-cli` prerenders your app in Node, where browser globals (such as `window`) do not exist.

If you've added a window check but are still getting the same error, that means you have other code also trying to access `window`. Each offending use will need to be wrapped in a window check if you want to prerender your app.

If you want to make a discussion on the [`preact-cli` repo](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/discussions) and provide your app, I can try to take a look.

---

Edit: The issue is in an upstream dependency of `axios`, `form-data`. This has an unsound browser vs Node check, meaning any use of `axios` at all will throw an error. The simplest solution would be to patch `form-data/lib/browser.js` with the following snippet:

```js
module.exports = typeof self == 'object' ? self.FormData : typeof window !='undefined' ? window.FormData : undefined;
```

https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/discussions/1784

Comment: the window check doesn't work at all, commenting out the code or writing something like if(1+1 == 3) instead of if(typeof window !== 'undefined') works. Will make a discussion on the preact-cli repo in a bit, thanks!

Comment: That would only happen if something's defining `window`, which is rather horrifying and very bad for any build tool, not just `preact-cli`. Basically you're just looking for a condition that's only true in a browser, so Node skips it. `window` is the standard, but there are other things you could test against too to varying degrees of success (some of those conditions are commonly polyfilled, so effectiveness depends a bit on what you're using).